# tsung postgresql ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Tags: tsung

I'm trying to do load test postgresql db using tsung.
I used pgsql.xml provided in examples folder in tsung-1.5.0.

- Here's my pgsql.xml: https://github.com/processone/tsung/blob/master/examples/pgsql.xml.in
- I run tsung using `tsung -f test.xml -p pgsql start`.
- I got the following error:

  > ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Could anyone point me out what the problem is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using server monitoring and your SSH is not setup..

```
<monitoring>
<monitor host="localhost"/>
</monitoring>
```

Do you really want to monitor server? If not then you can comment the code and it should work fine..  If yes then you will have to set up a password less SSH to your server...